# Application: Application Launcher, can't Move directory, it's being used by another process

Tags: c#, .net

I'm writing application launcher as a Window Application in C#, VS 2017. Currently, having problem with this piece of code:

```
 if (System.IO.Directory.Exists(extractPath))
        {
            string[] files = System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(extractPath);
            string[] dirs = Directory.GetDirectories(extractPath);

            // Copy the files and overwrite destination files if they already exist.
            foreach (string s in files)
            {
                // Use static Path methods to extract only the file name from the path.
                var fileName = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(s);
                var destFile = System.IO.Path.Combine(oldPath, fileName);
                System.IO.File.Move(s, destFile);
            }

            foreach (string dir in dirs)
            {
                //var dirSplit = dir.Split('\\');
                //var last = dirSplit.Last();
                //if (last != "Resources")
                //{
                    var fileName = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(dir);
                    var destFile = System.IO.Path.Combine(oldPath, fileName);
                    System.IO.Directory.Move(dir, destFile);
                //}
            }
        }
```

I'm getting well known error 
"The process cannot access the file 'XXX' because it is being used by another process."

I was looking for solution to fix it, found several on MSDN and StackOvervflow, but my problem is quite specific. I cannot move only 1 directory to another, which is Resources folder of my main application:
[image: Resources folder]

Here is my explanation why problem is specific:

1. I'm not having any issues with moving other files from parent directory. Error occurs only when loop reaches /Resources directory.
2. At first, I was thinking that it's beeing used by VS instantion, in which I've had main app opened. Nothing have changed after closing VS and killing process.
3. I've copied and moved whole project to another directory. Never opened it in VS nor started via *.exe file, to make sure that none of files in new, copied directory, is used by any process.
4. Finally, I've restarted PC.

I know that this error is pretty common when you try to Del/Move files, but in my case, I'm sure that it's being used only by my launcher app. Here is a little longer sample code to show what files operation I'm actually doing:

```
private void RozpakujRepo()
    {
        string oldPath = @"path\Debug Kopia\Old";
        string extractPath = @"path\Debug Kopia";

        var tempPath = @"path\ZipRepo\RexTempRepo.zip";

         if (System.IO.File.Exists(tempPath) == true)
          {
        System.IO.File.Delete(tempPath);
        }

     System.IO.Compression.ZipFile.CreateFromDirectory(extractPath, tempPath);


        if (System.IO.Directory.Exists(oldPath))
        {
            DeleteDirectory(oldPath);
        }
        if (!System.IO.Directory.Exists(oldPath))
        {
            System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(oldPath);
        }

        if (System.IO.Directory.Exists(extractPath))
        {
            string[] files = System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(extractPath);
            string[] dirs = Directory.GetDirectories(extractPath);

            // Copy the files and overwrite destination files if they already exist.
            foreach (string s in files)
            {
                // Use static Path methods to extract only the file name from the path.
                var fileName = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(s);
                var destFile = System.IO.Path.Combine(oldPath, fileName);
                System.IO.File.Move(s, destFile);
            }

            foreach (string dir in dirs)
            {
                //var dirSplit = dir.Split('\\');
                //var last = dirSplit.Last();
                //if (last != "Resources")
                //{
                    var fileName = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(dir);
                    var destFile = System.IO.Path.Combine(oldPath, fileName);
                    System.IO.Directory.Move(dir, destFile);
                //}
            }
        }

        string zipPath = @"path\ZipRepo\RexRepo.zip";



        ZipFile.ExtractToDirectory(zipPath, extractPath);
    }
```

And now, my questions:

1. Can it be related to file types (.png, .ico, .bmp) ?
2. Can it be related to fact, that those resources files are being used like, as, for example .exe file icon in my main application? Or just because those are resources files?
3. Is there anything else what I'm missing and what can cause the error?

EDIT:

To clarify:
There are 2 apps:

1. Main Application
2. Launcher Application (to launch Main Application)

And Resources folder is Main Application/Resources, I'm moving it while I'm doing application version update.

Comment: If its the resources folder for the app itself, then yes it will be number 2 as the app itself is using those files.

Comment: You've missunderstood. There are 2 apps - Main Application and Launcher Application (to launch Main Application). And this is resources folder of Main Application

Comment: Ah well in that case; I've come across that error before due to the folder being the current path on a cmd/powershell window, or having the folder open in explorer. If you haven't tried yet, you could use process explorer from the sysinternals suite, to see what process has a handle to the folder.

Comment: @CodedBeard I'll try to track it down with Process Explorer, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It appeared that problem is in different place than in /Resources directory. Actually problem was with /Old directory, because it caused inifinite recurrence.